# What is the Simultaneous connections allowed in Cloud Firestore for Spark Plan

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is the simultaneous connections allowed in Cloud Firestore for Spark Plan?
For Realtime Database Simultaneous connections is 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acording to the official documentation regarding [Firestore Quotas](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), the realtime maximum concurrent connections updates is:

> Maximum concurrent connections for mobile/web clients per database: 1,000,000

Comment: for Spark Plan?

Comment: Yes and this is because Cloud Firestore offers free quota that allows you to get started at no cost.